# java.lang.InstantiationError: org.primefaces.util.Lazy when updating primefaces 7 to primefaces 8

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 7 in my project. I have to update it primefaces 8 for using multiple file upload. I updated the jar files with the new ones. When I tried to run my project on wildfly, I'm getting this error.

```
16:17:16,058 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) Critical error during deployment: : java.lang.InstantiationError: org.primefaces.util.Lazy
    at org.primefaces.csp.CspPhaseListener.<init>(CspPhaseListener.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.addPhaseListeners(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:294)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:292)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:205)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

16:17:16,060 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."TECIntranet.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."TECIntranet.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.primefaces.util.Lazy
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.primefaces.util.Lazy
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.primefaces.util.Lazy
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:283)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.primefaces.util.Lazy
    at org.primefaces.csp.CspPhaseListener.<init>(CspPhaseListener.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.addPhaseListeners(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:294)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:292)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:205)
    ... 22 more

16:17:16,151 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "TECIntranet.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"TECIntranet.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.primefaces.util.Lazy
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.primefaces.util.Lazy
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.primefaces.util.Lazy
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.primefaces.util.Lazy"}}
```

My wildfly version: 16.0.0
My javax version: 2.1

I changed the primefaces-7.0.jar with primefaces-8.0.jar but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Have you checked the migration guide (https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/8_0)? There are changed to fileupload between 7 and 8.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6189

You have multiple PrimeFaces versions being loaded in your WAR/EAR file.

Comment: in my case due to the 'add framework support' feature in intellij I had a different version of the jar in the directory TARGET/XXX-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib.